# Putting the Criterions into List for 'OR' condition

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-criteria

I have the requirement where I need to use `Criterion` for `or` condition. This `Criterion` will be created in loop. So I am adding the `Criterion` into a `List`. And outside of the loop I am adding these `Criterion`'s into `Criteria` and typecasting the list(which contains the `Criterion`) into `Criterion[]` array.

```
List<Criterion> criterions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
        for (XYZ xyz : xyzs) {

            Integer[] age = findMinAndMaxAgeXYZ(xyz);

            Date minAge = prepareDateByAge(age[0]);
            Date maxAge = prepareDateByAge(age[1]);
            // Ordering has been changed to fetch the records for 
            // between condition.
            criterions.add(Restrictions.between("dob", maxAge, minAge));
        }
        criteria.add(Restrictions.or((Criterion[]) criterions.toArray()));
```

But it gives me exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
```

Any other solution to add the `Criterion` as `or` instead of putting into the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toArray()` returns an array of Object. What you need is an array of Criterion. So the correct method is:

```
Criterion[] array = criterions.toArray(new Criterion[criterions.size()]);
```

See the different return type between [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) and [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29)

Note that, in this case, it would be much easier to simply use a disjunction:

```
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
for (XYZ xyz : xyzs) {
    ...
    disjunction.add(Restrictions.between("dob", maxAge, minAge));
}
criteria.add(disjunction);
```